# Is there any way to synchronise the clock of my avd

Tags: android, twitter, twitter4j, jtwitter, synclock

I am using android virtual device for android developing and i am developing an app to update status in twitter and seeing the logcat i think the problem is that it's system clock is not synchronised can anyone please help.

Logcat

```
12-06 09:23:25.693: W/System.err(537): 401:Authentication credentials (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth) were missing or incorrect. Ensure that you have set valid conumer key/secret, access token/secret, and the system clock in in sync.
```

Complete code is in [here](http://sayemsiam.blogspot.com/2011/12/status-update-in-twitter-using.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to customize your emulator's settings:

1.Disable network provided values:
1.1. Settings -> Date & Time 
1.2. uncheck first row 
2. Set correct time:
2.1. Settings -> Date & Time 
2.2. fourth row (Set time)

Hope this helps.